# Level Translator 3.3V to -7V with drive

Tags: operational-amplifier, single-supply-op-amp, level-translation

I am retrofitting a circuit in existing equipment.  I need a circuit for each direction.
Circuit 1:
3.3V logic input.  Output is GND or -7V with a load of 20k to 200k and 2nF.  25kHz or less.  Drive is 50mA minimum.

Current design (I am using -12 instead of -7 due to testbench only having -12V).  This circuit with TLC2272 opamp has slow rise on breadboard.  I want to switch to use ADA4895-1ARJZ-R7 opamp but with ADA4895-1ARJZ-R opamp, point 2 is always -2V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffxeqi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Circuit 2:
GND to -7V input (load 20k to 200k, 2nF).  Output is 3.3V logic to processor.  The circuit appears to work correctly with a TLC2272 opamp.  When the input is more negative than the reference of -1.3V I get GND and when it is more positive I get 3.3V output.  I want to switch to the ADA4895-1ARJZ-R7 opamp, will it work the same?

Design so far:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv5C1e.png)</sup>

Comment: Have you got a question?

Comment: In your first circuit, the point marked "4-Gnd" cannot be at -2 V, as it is directly connected to your -12 V supply.

Comment: Something doesn't add up in the second diagram, you have a -5.8 reference and the output is 0 to 3.3V, which means that the output will likely always be railed.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to clear up some of the confusion and correct the drawing.

Comment: I updated the post.  circuit 1, I meant point 2 is always -2 with the ADA opamp.  Circuit 2 works as is, but I want to switch to a smaller footprint opamp like the ADA opamp.  Will it work the same.  Hard to breadboard the tiny parts.

Comment: On first circuit, node 3 is biased to -2.1V but input ranges from 0 to 3.3V(?), so op-amp output will stay near negative rail voltage.

Comment: Circuit 1 works correctly but has slow rise time. Input to node 2 is not 0 to 3.3V, the resistor divider changes the 3.3V to a negative voltage for comparison to a negative voltage.  The QUESTION is why doesn't this work with the ADA opamp (ADA opamp has faster rise time and better output drive).

Comment: Please **edit your question for completeness**.  What is your load?  What is "slow" -- my "slow rise time" may be "eh, takes a minute"; yours may be "takes a picosecond".  What is the character of the load?  Does the output need to be actively pulled both high and low, or just to ground, or just to -7V?.

Comment: @KeithHines Keith, the 50 mA spec is one that excludes a lot of the cheaper opamps. Personally? I'd prefer a solution using 3 or 4 BJTs because I can control the entire design that way and not depend upon less common opamp devices. Your rate is quite easy to handle with discrete parts and the output drive is almost trivial. As Tim mentions, edges matter though. You do need a negative rail. From this post, I gather you have one at -12 V. Is that correct? Also, are you willing to consider a circuit that doesn't use an opamp? Do you also have a positive rail available? If so, is it +3.3 V?

Comment: You state that the load is 20 to 200 k-ohms, presumably to ground -- but then you say the thing needs to drive 50mA.  \$7\mathrm V / 20 \mathrm k \Omega = 350 \mathrm{\mu A}\$: where does the 50mA figure come from?  Is that 50mA when the output is at 0V, or 50mA when the output is at -7V?

Comment: Did you read the datasheets of the parts you're using? TLC2272 cannot provide 50mA drive, period. In fact, very few low-cost op-amps could drive your load given that current requirement. For the inputs, you don't really need any op-amps. Two series diodes bypassed with a capacitor, a resistor to limit current, and a pull-up.

Comment: @KeithHines Also, is it desired that a -7 V input yields 0 V? Or when input is +3.3 V? I'm uncertain right now. (I'm assuming a push-pull output is desired that can source from ground towards a more negative rail or can sink into -7 V from a more positive one. I am *not* thinking about 4-quadrant.)

Comment: @Kubahasn I mentioned that a couple of comments above. And I suspect the OP is already at least vaguely aware. But it never hurts to keep bringing it up, too. The OP needs to write, now.

Comment: Answering all the questions in comments:
1) 50 mA is from a spec.  It only says must be able to drive at least 50mA.  A long cable (10 feet) is used.
2) The rise time with the TL2272 is about 10 uSeconds which is 1/4 of the 25KHz rate.  I need less then 1 usec.
3) I am NOT using the TL2272 because of size and drive problems.  I am trying to figure out how to make this circuit work with the ADA4895-1ARJZ-R7CT which has the correct drive.
4) I am INTERESTED in any solution including diodes or BJTs. @jonk  I have +5V, +3.3V and negative 7
Board space is an issue.

Comment: @kuba-hasnt-forgotten-monica  i would be interested in the diode circuit please

Answer (score 1):

There are some optimizing thoughts. For example, a 3-resistor divider group could translate your LO input voltage into sufficiently useful negative domain to save a BJT. But how do I balance the trade-off? I don't know. So I'm not going to offer alternatives as it would take me more time to work them out properly and explain them and I frankly don't have that time.

FYI, this will therefore be more of a *boilerplate* approach using BJTs:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIhCJ2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The input is presented to two cascode-arranged BJTs. The input loading is quite modest, as evidenced by the values of \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$. Their outputs drive CE-arranged BJTs operated as saturated switches with collector resistors arranged to limit current into the final output BJTs. The output BJTs are just the typical push-pull pair arrangement without any fluff added.

There's absolutely no short-circuit protection in this. It won't be good if there is a potential for shorting the output. And I didn't add anything to the cascode bases. They are directly bolted to power supply rails. This isn't ideal. But it saves parts. You really do want \$C_1\$, though. It sharpens the output, significantly.

There absolutely will be *shoot-through* in this circuit. I did nothing whatsoever to mitigate that problem. And frankly, that's probably the thing I like least about this circuit. But you said space is limited. So I'm not adding anything to help, here, other than what already exists in the current limiting resistors to the final output stage BJTs. Make sure you bypass the output drivers in this circuit.

And please do take note of the voltage rails that are used. I access all four of them: \$+3.3\:\text{V}\$, \$+5.0\:\text{V}\$, \$-7.0\:\text{V}\$, and ground. With added parts (voltage divider pair of resistors and a capacitor) the \$+3.3\:\text{V}\$ reference could instead refer to \$+5\:\text{V}\$. So if you find that tradeoff worth doing, there's that possibility.

---

If you want a hard-limit on the output current, it can be added. It will cost you half a volt on either end of the output, so you'll only get an output range from \$-500\:\text{mV}\$ to \$-6.5\:\text{V}\$ on the output. And you'll need two more BJTs and four more resistors. That's the price. But you'll get a max shoot-through of twice the limit, reducing the bypass capacitor need and/or reducing its value, and it will take a dead-short at the output without wincing.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDmElk.png)</sup>

You can tie the output of that to anything and it will self-limit the current. But it will also shave some of your output voltage range.

Answer (score 0):

A basic level-shifting Schmitt trigger will do:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyp750.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: transient]

Use a comparator, not an op-amp. This design would need -7V, but you can get that easily from -12V via LM337 or similar. Transitions are at about 20% and 80% of input range. The subtractor of R1 and R2 makes the input waveform symmetric about the midpoint of Vss to avoid clipping issues. No Vdd is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9xYZ5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit does not invert, if that's required you can add a CMOS inverter in front.

[image]