# Level translator 3.3 V logic to -7 V logic

Tags: level-shifting, level-translation

I am trying to replace a circuit on an old device.  I need to translate from 3.3 V logic to 0 to -7 V logic.  And vice-a-versa. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Circuit

- INPUT: 0 to 3.3 V logic from Arduino GPIO.
- OUTPUT: drives 25 kΩ to 200 kΩ load with 2nF capacitance.  Rate is 25 kHz.  - 50+ mA drive required.
- 0 V causes output to be -7 V.  3.3 V causes output to be 0 V.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Level Translator 3.3V to -7V with drive](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/573296/level-translator-3-3v-to-7v-with-drive). You already asked the same question. How is this question any different?

Comment: look for "logic voltage translation", and mentally shift your negative supply (whatever you have that needs -7V will probably also have a negative supply, e.g. -12V) to 0V, to make this all much easier. Suddenly your +3V ends up at +15V, your 0V at +12V, and all you need to do is to shift by 7V and amplify by 7/3.3

Comment: Keith, the 50 mA spec is one that excludes a lot of the cheaper opamps. Personally? I'd prefer a solution using 3 or 4 BJTs because I can control the entire design that way and not depend upon less common opamp devices. Your rate is quite easy to handle with discrete parts and the output drive is almost trivial. You do need a negative rail. From your earlier post, I gather you have one at -12 V. Is that correct? Also, are you willing to consider a circuit that doesn't use an opamp?

Comment: @Keith Please edit your previous question